# [DART]- Check if a value exists in a list of objects

Tags: list, flutter, dart

I've got an Abstract class named QuizzAnswer and I've a class named QuizzAnswerMCQ which extends QuizzAnswer class.

```
abstract class QuizzAnswer extends Equatable {}

 class QuizzAnswerMCQ extends QuizzAnswer {
  String optionId;
  bool isSelected;

 QuizzAnswerMCQ({required this.optionId, required this.isSelected});

   @override
   List<Object?> get props => [optionId, isSelected];

   Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
      "option_id": optionId,
       "is_selected": isSelected,
    };
 }
```

and I've got a list which is of type QuizzAnswerMCQ

```
List<QuizzAnswerMCQ> quizAnswerList=[];
```

and I add items to the list

```
quizAnswerList.add(QuizzAnswerMCQ(
      optionId: event.optionId, isSelected: event.optionValue));
```

what I want to do is to check if the optionId is already there in the list or not so I wrote this,

```
if(quizAnswerList.map((item) => item.optionId).contains(event.optionId)){
    print ('EXISTTTTSSSSS');
  }else{
    print('DOESNT EXISTTTT');
  }
```

Even though the optionId is there,I still get the output 'DOESNT EXISTTTT'.Please help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Do this

```
 if (quizAnswerList
          .where((element) => element.optionId == event.optionId)
          .isNotEmpty) {
         print ('EXISTTTTSSSSS');
      }
      else{  print('DOESNT EXISTTTT'); }
```

the .where() method checks and creates a list so if it's not empty then that item exists

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use **firstWhere** like this

```
result = quizAnswerList.firstWhere((item) => item.optionId == your_id);
```

or checking from other List

```
result = quizAnswerList.firstWhere((item) => otherList.contains(item));
```

then

```
    if(result.length > 0){
      print ('');
    }else{
      print(');
    }
```

Official doc [here](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.1/dart-core/Iterable/firstWhere.html#:%7E:text=firstWhere%20method%20Null%20safety&text=Returns%20the%20first%20element%20that,defaults%20to%20throwing%20a%20StateError.)